# ReactJs : How to load react functional components selectively at startup?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-functional-component

I am trying to load components only when clicked instead of loading all during startup.

**index.js:**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js:**

```
    const App = (props) => {
      return (
     <React.Fragment> 
        <AProvider>
           <Route exact path="/A" component={A} />
         <AProvider>
          <BProvider>
            <Route exact path="/B" component={B} />
          </BProvider>
          <CProvider>
            <Route exact path="/C" component={C} />
          </CProvider>
          <DProvider>
            <Route exact path="/" component={D} />
          </DProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
      )};
     export default App;
```

My each provider component is making a get call to an endpoint to get data for the component

```
export const AContext = React.createContext();
export const AProvider = (props) => {
  const [A, setA] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getA() {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get(http://localhost/a", {
          params: {
            id: 1,
          },
        });
        setA(result.data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    getA();
  }, []);
  return (
    <AContext.Provider value={[A, setA]}>
      {props.children}
    </AContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

When I browse the root of my site on http://localhost:3000/, I expect to load only component D, but when I look at the browser network calls I see get calls for all the four components, instead of only loading the component of the route, How do i selectively load components? I have tried react-loadable and React.Lazy but it still makes all the four calls. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying there are 4 XHR/Ajax requests? That would make sense as App.js is rendering A, B, C and D Providers. Each of these components make an XHR/Ajax request.

Comment: From what I can see, the logic within the Provider-related components should be handled within the route-related components. This will ensure that only the required calls will be triggered based on the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason all Providers are invoked is because you don't render them within a Route. The correct way to invoke components on specific routes is to render them as Route children and not as Route wrappers

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
     <React.Fragment> 
           <Route exact path="/A" render={(rp) => <AProvider><A {...rp} /></AProvider>} />
            <Route exact path="/B" render={(rp) => <BProvider><B {...rp} /></BProvider>} / />
            <Route exact path="/C" render={(rp) => <CProvider><C {...rp} /></CProvider>} / />
            <Route exact path="/" render={(rp) => <DProvider><D {...rp} /></DProvider>} / />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};
export default App;
```

Comment: I didn't see documentation to this anywhere.